# Academic name for graphs which curve like a bridge

Tags: word-choice, academia, ielts

These are the images of the graphs I want to know the academic names:

[image: bell-shaped curve]    [image: upside down bell-shaped curve]

I've googled and learnt that their names are ***Concave Down Curve*** and ***Concave Up Curve***. However, I want to know if there are any other names for these graphs as I want to use them in a sentence like:

> "The sales from 2011 to 2017 resembles a concave down curve with the lowest point being 2015 at 20,356 sales"

**Edit 1**: Guys, thank you for your inputs.
However, my question was not that related to math, but was to find a good descriptive sentence for my IELTS writing. Here is the graph I came across in the test:

[image: bar chart image taken from IELTS Writing task 1 paper]

I noticed that, as people get older, women tend to do more exercises, and then less, their trend shapes like a bridge, while a reversion of that can be seen in men. Now, if I were to compare these two trends while trying to sound academic, should I write something similar to the following?

> "A demographic trend which resembles a concave down curve can be seen in women's figures while it is the opposite for men's"

Could you guys give me a more well structured and better sentence without sacrificing the "concave down curve or u-shaped curve" because I really want to include those terms.

Comment: 'U-shaped curve' is standard, but reasonably similar-shaped (in the everyday sense) graphs may be said to 'resemble a parabola etc'. But this is better asked on Mathematics SE.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Thank you Edwin, could you tell me what's the name of the other curve? Is it upside down U shaped curve? and can those "concave up/down curves" be used in formal writing? Thank you very much

Comment: 'Inverted U-shaped curve'. 'Concave up' etc are also commonly used, but apply to parts of graphs. See [mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz](http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Calculus/Sign2ndDer/Sign2DerPOI.htm).

Comment: They're both *parabolas*; they're more common of architectural arches than brides. Actual suspension bridges, like the Golden Gate Bridge, have a different curve, known as a a *catenary*.

Comment: Guys, thank you very much, i've made an edit for the question, could you guys help me out a bit?. Thanks.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth

Comment: @Dan Bron       
(Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.)

Comment: @user1661469
 (Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.)

Comment: [Concave and convex](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/concave-up-down-convex.html) would be understood by mathematicians.

Comment: If you want to describe the gentle rise and fall of a "line graph" then you could say that it **gradually peaks at.....** and then **there is a subtle decline thereafter.** Knowing the academic name for this type of slope doesn't tell your readers anything about the hard data, you should say WHICH age group, and WHICH sex  did the most **physical exercise** in the study conducted. Otherwise it's a very good question :)

Comment: Thank you @Mari-Lou A, i want you to know that your edit and answer are really appreciated by me. However, IELTS writing task 1 requires us not to simply report the graph but to compare it. That's why i was really keen on contradicting the 2 genders' figures.

Comment: *contrasting* the two genders...

Comment: @DanBron Not quite right. Suspension bridge cables, including the [Golden Gate Bridge](http://mathforum.org/mathimages/index.php/Parabolic_Bridges) are actually parabolic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requires specialist maths terminology for the best answer.

Comment: input, no s, if you are studying for that exam. In a factory, you might conceivably use inputs.

Answer (score 3):

This being sales data and not a pure function, I wouldn't advise using an academic description. I'd expect sales data at a micro-level to move in a geometric manner, due to the nature of communication. The example graphs look polynomial.

If I were instructing someone to draw this graph, I would tell them to draw **a parabola whose endpoints approach positive/negative infinity**.

Referring to the "low point," I'd call it **this valley's local minimum**. Unless it was the lowest point in the range, which would be the **absolute minimum**.

Comment: parabola is the simplest curve after straight lines, according to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Positive convexity means concave up. Negative convexity means concave down. The positive and negative refer to the positive/negative value of the rate of change of the function f'. (To understand the meaning rate of change you need to at least do Calculus 1)

It is a commonly used term in finance.

See definitions below:

[Investopedia: Convexity](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/convexity.asp)

[Corporate Finance Institute: Negative Convexity](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/trading-investing/negative-convexity/#:%7E:text=is%20Negative%20Convexity%3F-,Negative%20convexity%20occurs%20when%20a%20bond%27s%20duration%20increases%20in%20conjunction,value%20as%20interest%20rates%20decline).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the shape of your graphs, it is best to simply say that the percentage for women increases and then decreases, while that for men decreases and then increases.

Comment: That's a bit too generic, it doesn't really describe the gentle rise and fall. I'm sure you can do better.

Comment: Just saying the percentage for women increases then decreases is too vague. Does it dramatically increases, or does it climb steadily but slowly? And by how much? A 2% and a 25% rise both show an increase but only one of them is significant. In the bar chart displayed, the difference between the lowest and the highest percentage of women is just under 6%. As you can see, I used no technical words but the description reflects more accurately the actual graph.

Comment: Jasper Loy...poof, gone again.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase I've seen for the first curve is "Inverted-U Function". Examples are:

[Inverted-U Hypothesis](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/inverted-U+hypothesis)
[Inverted-U Function](https://www.britannica.com/science/inverted-U-function)

And the second graph is called a "U-Curve":

[Midlife Crisis? Or Just Bottoming Out on the U-Curve of Happiness](http://midlifeandthriving.com/2016/10/08/midlife-crisis-just-bottoming-u-curve-happiness/)
[Happiness, stress, and age: How the U-curve varies across people and places](https://www.brookings.edu/research/happiness-stress-and-age-how-the-u-curve-varies-across-people-and-places/)

Answer (score 0):

The curve is called a 'catenary', the curve of a cable or chain suspended at two points, while under the influence of gravity.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64240/why-wont-a-tight-cable-ever-be-fully-straight

Comment: The curves OP shows aren't catenaries. Their 'like a bridge' descriptor is somewhat misleading.